# How to center list

Tags: html, css

If I have a `<select>` list on my html page:

```
<body>
<div id="side-bar">...</div>
<div id="list">
       <select id="mylist" size="10"></select>
</div>
</body>
```

How to CSS mylist to make it located in the middle of the `<div id="list">` area? (Both **horizontally** and **vertically**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `#mylist {margin: 0 auto}`. It centers only the select element. If you want to center all the content within your div then `#list { text-align: center; }` should do the trick.

EDIT:

To center the select tag both vertically and horizontally you can do like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#list {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fa2;
}
#mylist {
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -50px;
}
</style>
<div id="list">
       <select id="mylist">
           <option value="1">test</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried #list { text-align: center; }, but your method only put the list horizontally to be center, not vertically.

Answer (score 2):

A style of `#list {text-align:center; }` should do it, though that will horizontally center *everything* within your div.

To horizontally center just the `select` element, you can use `#mylist { margin: 0px auto; }`. Check out http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html for more details about how this works.

In order to center vertically, the "simplest" approach would be to use an HTML table with a cell style that contains `vertical-align:middle;`. For a non-table-based approach you can use something like this http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution, but this approach is a bit hacky.

If you know (or can set) the height of your containing `div`, then a combination of `relative` and `absolute` positioning along with a containing `div` for `select` might work for you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div
        {
            border: 1px solid black; /* just so we can see the div */
        }
        #list
        {
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
        }
        #list div
        {
            position:absolute;
            top: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="list">
            <div>
                <select id="mylist" size="10"><option>option 1</option><option>option 2</option></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I've tested this in IE9, FireFox 4 and Chrome 11)

Comment: Hi, I have changed my question, I would like to put mylist in the middle of the div id='list' area. As you saw above, I have also side-bar area on the page.

Comment: @Leem: Selects are inline elements so that should still do it.

Comment: To prevent this, could you create a separate div inside of #list, like #list_container, that is "text-align:left; margin:0 auto;" and a set width. That would make the list centered without centering the text as well.

Comment: your method only put the list horizontally to be center, not vertically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this..

```
#mylist{margin-left auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

Comment: This only center the text inside the list

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go for:

```
#list {
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

- `text-align: center` to horizontally center.
- `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle` to vertically center.

This will work in IE8+ and all modern browsers.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/knvV2/