# How to center a <img> html tag with css, in Opera?

Tags: html, css, opera, centering

I have the following CSS code being used for centering an `<img>` tag

```
.img {
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
}
```

The above code works an intended in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and IE8.

**But it does not work in Opera**

If i add `padding-top` to the above code, it messes up the other browsers but opera works.

How do I target Opera for `padding-top` or solve the centering issue with Opera ?

Comment: Are you able to just use the image as a background image? `background:#fff url('img.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;` would work.

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute` to center it? Where did you find that technique? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you know the size of the image or is it variable?

Comment: @thirtydot,  the img tag is under a div with position: relative;

Comment: @Ibn Saeed: So you're trying to make this image appear underneath *everything* and be horizontally centered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is center the image all you need to do is:

```
img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put your Image in an Div Box and then Center it.

```
#image {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

you only have to adjust the `height` and the `width` of your Div Box

Answer (score 0):

Try removing top, right, bottom, left.

```
img {
      position:absolute;
      margin: auto;
      /*If it doesn't do it, try to add display: block; also*/
}
```

and make sure you are referencing the tag `img` and not the class `.img` but I presume that was only a typo.

Comment: Yes, im targeting the img tag, and not the class. I removed the the top, left, right, bottom and it broke in all the browsers, and its not centering anywhere. I need to use atleast top and bottom to be 0, for it to be centered

Comment: Do you want to center it vertically and horizontally? This answer, might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112125/css-newbie-how-to-center-my-list/6112183#6112183 . I don't think you should use position:absolute and set any of the four attributes(top, right, bottom, left) to 0 and expect it to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JavaScript Navigator object to identify that the browser is Opera or not `navigator.appName`

I've never personally used it since I use jQuery, but for such a small thing, jQuery would be a large overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it with a

```
<div id="div" ....>
  <img ...>
</div>
```

and the style

```
#div {
    width:980px;
margin:10px auto 40px auto;
}
```

I use this often to center my Website.
Maybe it works directly on the img.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is to center the image there is set of solutions the fist is to put the element in `<center>` tag the second solution depend on the image width for example if the image width is 300 you can use this code `.img{position:absolute;left: 50%;margin-left: -150px;}`

and it is a bad practice to use the `top:0` with `bottom:0`

Answer (score 0):

I just test tested it in Chrome and IE 10.

```
<div style="margin: 0 25%; width:800px;">
   <img src="~/Images/yourimage.png" width="300" height="300" style=" margin: auto;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is like :

```
//html (no css is needed)
 <center><img src = ""></center>
```